# libusb is in the path but the linker doesn't find it

Tags: gcc, linker

Usually when the linker doesn't find a library that actually exists in the path it's because some binary incompatibilities (i.e. about 32/64 bit).
In my situation it seems different and I didn't find a question that answer the issue.

Rapsberry Pi 3B+, Raspbian Stretch Lite, trying to compile the Microchip SDK for 3DTouchPad.

The compilation fails in this way:

```
mkdir -p build/bin
gcc -o build/bin/2draw build/2draw/2draw.o  -Lbuild/bin -lmchp_hmi -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -lusb -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:125: recipe for target 'build/bin/2draw' failed
make: *** [build/bin/2draw] Error 1
```

and here the details about the "missing" library:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libusb
    libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6,hard-float) => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0
    libusb-1.0.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
    libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6,hard-float) => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-0.1.so.4

$ file /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0 
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=a93e56d2846806b7adc76e674493c76e54e3ca9e, stripped
```

That seems ok to me. I installed it with `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev`.

Are there any other causes that would prevent the linker to find an existing library?

### EDIT

Interesting enough... even I cannot infer the cause.

```
$ ld -lusb --verbose
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.28
  Supported emulations:
   armelf_linux_eabi
   armelfb_linux_eabi

==================================================
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libusb.a failed
attempt to open //usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libusb.so failed
attempt to open //usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libusb.a failed
ld: cannot find -lusb
```

Comment: Passing `-lusb-1.0` to the linker seems to fix the error. But I thought the versioning of the so files were taken in account automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an argument of the form `-lLIB`, the link editor looks for input files named `libLIB.so` or `libLIB.a`.  If there is a version number in the library name `LIB`, you must supply it, otherwise the link editor will not find it.  If the version is in the soname *after* the `.so`, it is customary to add a dynamic link ending in `.so` without the version, so that the link editor can find it.  (This symbolic link is usually packaged in the `-dev` or `-devel` packages by distributions.)  But in your case, this symbolic link includes the version number *before* the `.so` (although it would not have to).

One advantage of putting the version number in the library name (the `LIB` part above) is that it is possible to easily switch between linking against different versions of the library.